# How to find number of special characters in sting in objective C

Tags: objective-c, count, nsstring, special-characters, nscharacterset

Help me find the same, tried searching many questions all I found was  to check if the string contains a special character, but I want to find the number of special characters in a string in objective - c

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow — please update your question to show what you have tried, and specific examples of what you want the function to do. See: [ask], [mre]

Comment: There is no function to automatically do that for you. You should write your own code. One way is to use an NSMutableDictionary to keep track of the count as you traverse the characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *abcd = @",;ab/bn']jkfg\";
        NSString *specialCharacterString = @"!~`@#$%^&*-+();:={}[],.<>?\/\"\'";
        int count = 0;
        for (NSUInteger i=0;i<[abcd length];i++){
           for(NSUInteger j=0;j<[specialCharacterString length];j++){
               if ([abcd characterAtIndex:i]==[specialCharacterString characterAtIndex:j]){
                   NSLog(@"found: %d", i);
                   count++;
               }
           }